# Handling large GET requests in laravel and displaying them

Tags: php, laravel, get-request

I'm currently working on a Laravel / VueJS SPA where i'm making a GET (through file_get_contents) request to receive orders from a 3rd party API. Everything works as intended except that i only get 100 orders (limit?) back. Currently there are 1.064 orders in the 3rd party API but this is increasing by the day.

How can i GET & display all orders instead of just the last 100 and what would be the best way to handle such amount of volume ? I imagine displaying all orders as i'm currently displaying the 100 gets out of control soon enough. Could this be done through pagination for example or would i have to store the data in a DB?

My GET for clarification:

```
private static function makeRequest($method, $endpoint)
{
    $username = $_ENV['API_KEY'];
    $url = "https://foo.foo.com//api/v1";

    // Create a stream
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => $method,
            'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:"),
            'user_agent' => "foo(foo.foo.com/api - john@doe.com)"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    return file_get_contents("$url/$endpoint", false, $context);
}
```

Example of the Dashboard (here i list all 100 orders):
[image]

Tips on how to go about are very welcome!

Comment: when you access data of get api via browser or postman, do you get all the orders? or there are hundred you can get large data using guzzle in stream. Also note there are some apis which send data as per the amount you want if you don't send any they send a fixed value by default. check that your api does the same or not

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the case! The api has a fixed length of 100 orders, it was just poorly documented. I will have to use an offset

Answer (score 0):

you need to create pagination when getting the data, limit that data as you wish, per 10, 50, or 100. it's a basic thing when you get a large amount of data, hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, however would this also solve the issue that i only get back 100 orders from my GET request?